# Can the commitment be fulfilled by asking questions only?

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-fulfillment

I have a question about fulfilling commitment. I'm participating in private beta of English Language Learners. Because I classify myself as learner, I'm concentrated only on asking questions, because I feel my knowledge and 'Sprachsgefühl' is still too little to provide answers which may prove wrong and misleading.

I've simply chosen those proposal for asking questions, and I have a bunch of them in mind.

But, can I fulfill that commitment only asking questions, or should I try to give answers, even if I don't feel confident enough?

Comment: The commitment pledge (when you click the Commit link) says: *"I commit to participate actively in [Site Name] for at least three months, especially during the private beta, and to ask or answer at least ten questions."*

Comment: Yes, however it does not specify, it it can be only 10 questions, or there is some hidden requirement that it must be at least 2 answers, for example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the commitment **can** be fulfilled by only asking questions.

I've just fulfilled my commitment on English Language Learners having 20 questions and no answer.

So you can fulfill commitment playing only the role of scholar or only a teacher.